# Loop to create crosstabs of columns using tidyr

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I would like to use a loop to create crosstabs of one column with every other column in a df. I started with this code (substituting in the iris df), which works nicely for two variables:

```
iris <- iris
tbl <- iris %>% 
  tabyl(Species, Sepal.Length, show_missing_levels = FALSE, show_na = FALSE) %>%
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 0) %>%
  adorn_ns() %>%
  adorn_title("combined") %>%
  knitr::kable()
print(tbl)
```

My df contains ~200 columns. I thought I would write a for loop to print a crosstab for one variable with each of the other variables. Here's what I tried:

```
cols <- c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')
for (c in cols){
  tbl <- iris %>% 
    tabyl(Species, c, show_missing_levels = FALSE, show_na = FALSE) %>%
    adorn_percentages("row") %>%
    adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 0) %>%
    adorn_ns() %>%
    adorn_title("combined") %>%
    knitr::kable()
  print(tbl)
}
```

This returns `` Column `c` is not found. ``

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use `!!sym(c)` instead of `c` inside the loop.  See `https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/bang-bang.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `c` in your code to `!!sym(c)`. I can't explain this non-standard tidyverse evaluation thingy, but in layman's terms, you want to access an object (i.e. "c") outside of your pipe (iris). That's why you need !!sym.

Comment: This worked, thank you! I get the gist of why the code needs to be that way, but will need to read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.data` pronoun when passing columns names as strings.

```
cols <- c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')

for (col in cols){
  tbl <- iris %>% 
    tabyl(Species, .data[[col]],show_missing_levels = FALSE,show_na = FALSE) %>%
    adorn_percentages("row") %>%
    adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 0) %>%
    adorn_ns() %>%
    adorn_title("combined") %>%
    knitr::kable()
  print(tbl)
}
```

Comment: This was helpful, thanks! I need to get more familiar with pronoun usage in tidy.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Although, it saves only the last iterated table. Is there an option to save all tables in one table? For instance `cbind()` them together since they have the same number of row?